# Implementing the 'kernel trick' for a support vector machine in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I've heard a bit about the 'kernel trick' for support vector machines, and I was wondering:

1. How do you identify problems that might benefit from the kernel trick?
2. How to implement it in R?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

7. Basically anything what is not separable with a line (ok, hyperplane), for instance 2D data like this:
   [image]
   kernel trick will effectively project this situation into a (higher-dim) space in which linear separation is possible; see this movie for an [effect of a gaussian kernel on similar data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NrALgHFwTo).
8. Look for a kernel argument in your svm function ;-) Note that using a kernel usually introduces new parameters to the outer optimization.

Comment: Would a radial kernel also work on this kind of data?

Comment: @Zach I think so; also polynomial one should be OK

Answer (score 3):

you should take a look at kernlab R package. They even have a very nice [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/vignettes/kernlab.pdf).